# Keep track of taps on a button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

Is there a way to keep count of how many times a user taps a button? i am hoping to perform a segue after the user taps a button so many times. As of right now I am having my backend keep track of how many taps.

```
@IBAction func nextbuttontest(sender: AnyObject) {

        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let view = button.superview!
        let cell = view.superview as! NewFeedControllerCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        let row = indexPath?.row

        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row!+1, inSection: 0), 
                                         atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, 
                                         animated: false)   
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create integer variable inside you view controller, and use it as a counter -> that is, when user taps increment it and if you have enough taps perform a segue or anything else.

For instance:

```
var tapCounter = 0
```

as a declaration in your view controller.

```
func tapGestureForElement(gest:UIGestureRecognizer){
    tapCounter = tapCounter + 1
    if(tapCounter == 123){
        //performSegue
    }
}
```

EDIT::

for the second part:

```
if(row!+1 == yourArray.count){ // or == 10, as you mentioned in comments, but I think that is a bad practice
    //do nothing or do something, up to you :)
{
else{
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row!+1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
}
```

Edit 2:

you can even do something better, you can check if you reached end of the rows in section:

```
if( row!+1 == tableView. numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)
```

Last part is not tested, but that should be it.

Comment: thanks! the button also scrolls to the next row, how do i make it so it doesnt scroll if the row doesn't exist???

Comment: for that one you should post your code,  I really don't know what are you doing :)

Comment: okay i posted the code in the original post, right now when it gets to the last row it crashes. I tried: if row != nil {, but that didnt work.

Comment: do you have any data source that determine how many rows do you have?

Comment: well im planning on having a query limit of 10, so it will return 10 rows, but if there aren't enough objects in parse it may return less than 10

Comment: Last part was it! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!! YOU DA BEST, DO NOT LET ANYONE EVER TELL YOU OTHERWISE!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Like NickCatib said, add a `tapCounter` property to your view controller. However, instead of manually firing the segue when the tap count reaches the desired value, override `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` so that it won't return `YES` for that particular segue until the tap count has been reached.